# Using Mobius Inversion Formula

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, arithmetic-functions, mobius-function, mobius-inversion

We are given the following:

$f(n)=\prod_{d|n}g(d)$

and asked to show:

$g(n)=\prod_{d|n} f(d)^{\mu(\frac{n}{d})}$

The hint given says to use logarithms

Here's what I tried doing:

$log(f(n))=\prod_{d|n}g(d) \\
log(f(n))=log \sum_{d|n} g(d) \\ 
k(n)=log \sum_{d|n} g(d) \\
e^k(n)=\sum_{d|n} g(d) \\
t(n)=\sum_{d|n} g(d)$

Thus $\{t(n), g(n)\}$ are a Mobius pair. Now,

$g(n)=\sum_{d|n} \mu(d)t(\frac{n}{d}) \\
=\mu(d)e^k(\frac{n}{d}) \\
=\sum_{d|n} \mu(d)e^{log(f(\frac{n}{d}))} \\
=\sum_{d|n} \mu(d)f(\frac{n}{d})$

Not sure where to go from here, or whether this is event the correct approach to begin with.